# Выбрать папку с помощью JavaScript или NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Доброго времени суток ребята.

**Вопрос:** есть ли способ на джаваскрипте или node.js выбрать любую папку и сохранить ее путь чтобы потом на сервере обработать содержимое папки?

Ищу, и нигде не могу найти информацию по этому вопросу.

Я знаю что в JavaScript есть ограничения в доступе к файловой системе, но если это решить с помощью node.js?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ограничения к файловой системе не у javascript, а у браузера

Comment: @Grundy Хорошо, но знаешь каким способом это сделать?

Comment: что сделать-то?

Comment: @Grundy Получить абсолютный путь к папке.

Comment: Получить абсолютный путь к какой папке?

Comment: Я говорю в общем, то есть открыть диалоговое окно и выбрать папку. Чтобы потом путь к этой папке отправить серверу на обработку ее содержимого.

Comment: _открыть диалоговое окно_ - в браузере?

Comment: диалоговое окно файловой системы, например когда выбираешь файл с помощью <input type='file'/>, а я хочу не файл а папку выбрать. Причем даже не саму папку а просто ее путь.

Comment: _<input type='file'/>_ - это html, значит речь идет про браузер, в браузере на это ограничения, поэтому никак нельзя

Comment: выбор папки с локальной машины невозможен, только файл, если пользователю необходимо выбрать папку на сервере то это решается просто.

Comment: используя nodejs-> require(__dirname+'файл');